# What is a rigorous proof that $\bigcap [n , \infty)$ is empty

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

There was a claim that a non empty chain $[n , \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ (unclear if $n \in \mathbb{R}$, or $\Bbb N$, I will assume the latter) have empty intersection $\bigcap [n , \infty)$

It doesn't seem to be visually clear exactly why this intersection would be empty. I attempted at a proof but I can't seem to find the problem showing it is empty.

So suppose $\bigcap [n , \infty) \neq \varnothing$, so $\exists z \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $z \in \bigcap [n , \infty) \implies z \in [n, \infty), \forall n$. We wish to produce a set $[n , \infty)$ such that $z \notin [n, \infty)$.

Again it doesn't seem possible to do this? can someone help?

Comment: If you can't "see" it visually, you are not thinking about it the right way. The right way is to say, "let me FIXATE on one particular $z \in\Bbb R$ and watch the $[n,\infty)$ go by in succession." Now do you see why eventually there will be such a set (member of the intersection) that will cease to contain that FIXED $z$? This is exactly what Avs's solution does, using formal language.

Comment: "We wish to produce a set [n,∞) such that z∉[n,∞) Again it doesn't seem possible to do this?"  Seriously?!  Of course it is!!!  Let $n  > z$  Then $z \not \in [n,\infty)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the Archimedean property, for every real $x$ there exists an integer $n > x$, so $[n, \infty)$ fails to contain $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your comment *It doesn't seem to be visually clear exactly why this intersection would be empty,* maybe this will help.

Assume that $x$ belongs to

$$[1,\,\infty) \; \cap \; [2,\, \infty) \; \cap \; [3,\, \infty) \; \cap \; [4,\, \infty) \; \cap \; [5,\, \infty) \; \cap \; [6,\, \infty) \; \cap \; \cdots$$

Since $\;x \in [1,\,\infty),\;$ it follows that $x \geq 1.$

Since $\;x \in [2,\,\infty),\;$ it follows that $x \geq 2.$

Since $\;x \in [3,\,\infty),\;$ it follows that $x \geq 3.$

Since $\;x \in [4,\,\infty),\;$ it follows that $x \geq 4.$

Since $\;x \in [5,\,\infty),\;$ it follows that $x \geq 5.$

Since $\;x \in [6,\,\infty),\;$ it follows that $x \geq 6.$

Can you see the problem? We pick an $x$ in the intersection of all these sets and, bit by bit, we find that there is nowhere on the real line where $x$ can live.

For a more rigorous proof, pick $x \in {\mathbb R}.$ (The result is clearly true if $x \not \in {\mathbb R}.$ Why?) Choose a positive integer $N$ such that $x < N.$ (Depending on what "rigor" means in your case, you might have to cite a reason why this can be done.) Then $x \not \in [N,\,\infty).$ (Why?) Hence, $x$ does not belong to the intersection of all these sets. (Why?) Hence, nothing belongs to the intersection of all these sets. (Why?)

Answer (score 2):

The thing to prove, when you do this rigorously is:

> The set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbdrs is not bounded above in $\mathbb R$.

Of course you need some rigorous definitions of $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$ to even have a chance of starting to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Visually, the statement tells you that if you go more and more "to the right right" on the number line, you will eventually go beyond *all* the numbers on that line.

In other words, for every $x$ there exists some $n$ such that $x\notin [n,\infty)$, which in other words translates to $x<n$.

It might be a bit more helpful to think about the intervals $[1-\frac1n,1)$, and try to understand how that intersection looks like. The argument there is the same, only limited to $(0,1)$ and not the entire number line.

Answer (score 0):

Such a $z$ would be $\ge n$ for every $n$, and there is no $z\in \mathbb R$ with this property

Answer (score 0):

Your $z\in [n,\infty)$ for all $n$. That means $z\geq n$ for all $n$.If $z$ is an integer $m$ then $z=m<m+1$. Contradiction. If $z$ is not an integer we know $[z]$ which is the smallest integer greater than $z$ is such that $[z]>z\geq [z]$. That is  $[z]>[z]$. Again contradiction.